# Simple method to control mp3 playback using c# for asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html5-audio

There is a simple method for playing mp3 files using html5, like so:

`<audio src="blah.mp3" controls="controls">
</audio>`

How can I start/stop the playback using c#?

(I'd like to avoid any lengthy javascript if possible)

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: C# runs on the server side while the audio is played by your browser on the client side... you cannot control the player without JavaScript.

Comment: Your c# code runs at server and audio is played on client's browser. Yes you can do it with SignalR + some javascript but are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: Use something such as jPlayer (www.jplayer.org) as you have no control from the server other than emitting javascript. Of course, that won't really help because once the page is served, you can't send more javascript to the browser.